# Consultando dado do input no banco - ASP + SQL

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Bom galera, sou mais que iniciante em ASP e JS e to me batendo aqui pra fazer algo que deve ser simples.

Eu tenho um input o qual vai ser preenchido com um valor "xxAMSxxxx/xx" e precisava validar esse valor no banco e uma vez que ele for verdadeiro, mostrar e preencher um pedaço de um form que vai ser salvo posteriormente. Tentei fazer isto mas não tive sucesso.

PS: Consegui pelo menos fazer o button dar block na div do form.

```
function mostraCampos() {
  if (document.getElementById("dsAmsReference").style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("dsAmsReference").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dsAmsReference").style.display = "none";
  }
}

<div class="input-control select novospan2 floatForm-left">
  Reserva AMS
  <input name="dsAmsReference" id="dsAmsReference" placeholder="Digite aqui a Ref" type="text">
</div>      

<% 

dim dsAmsReference 

dsAmsReference  = codificar(request("dsAmsReference")) 'não segura o valor


DIM ID_CD_CLIENTE,DS_AMS_REFERENCE,DS_VESSEL,DS_VOYAGE,DS_ORIGEM,DS_DESTINO,DS_ORIGEM_COLETA,DS_DESTINO_COLETA,NM_PESSOA,NR_CPF_CNPJ,DS_ENDERECO,DS_COMPLEMENTO,NM_CIDADE,NM_ESTADO,NR_CEP,NR_PREFIXO,NR_DDD,NR_TELEFONE

DIM NR_NETWEI

    objBD.SQL = "EXEC PR_DRAFT_DRAF_s @FUNCAO='S35', @DS_AMS_REFERENCE='"&dsAmsReference&"', @ID_CD_LOGIN='"&Session("ID_CD_LOGIN")&"'"
    'response.write(objBD.SQL)
    'response.end()
    objBD.executaSQlBasico                          
    if not objBD.RS.eof then 

        DS_AMS_REFERENCE            = objBD.RS("DS_AMS_REFERENCE")
        DS_VESSEL                   = objBD.RS("DS_VESSEL")
        DS_VOYAGE                   = objBD.RS("DS_VOYAGE")
        DS_ORIGEM                   = objBD.RS("DS_ORIGEM")
        DS_DESTINO                  = objBD.RS("DS_DESTINO")    
        DS_ORIGEM_COLETA            = objBD.RS("DS_ORIGEM_COLETA")
        DS_DESTINO_COLETA           = objBD.RS("DS_DESTINO_COLETA")
        NM_PESSOA                   = objBD.RS("NM_PESSOA")
        NR_CPF_CNPJ                 = objBD.RS("NR_CPF_CNPJ")
        DS_ENDERECO                 = objBD.RS("DS_ENDERECO")
        DS_COMPLEMENTO              = objBD.RS("DS_COMPLEMENTO")
        NM_CIDADE                   = objBD.RS("NM_CIDADE")
        NM_ESTADO                   = objBD.RS("NM_ESTADO")
        NR_CEP                      = objBD.RS("NR_CEP")
        NR_PREFIXO                  = objBD.RS("NR_PREFIXO")
        NR_DDD                      = objBD.RS("NR_DDD")
        NR_TELEFONE                 = objBD.RS("NR_TELEFONE")
        'response.write(objBD.SQL)
        'response.end()
    else
        objBD.LimpaRecordSet 
        objBD.FecharConexao
        response.Redirect("inicio.asp")         
        response.end()
    end if      

%>
 <!--#include file="teste-draft-js.asp"-->
<div class="input-control margBottom50 text span2 ">    
  <input type="submit" value="Validar Ref" onclick="mostraCampos();completaDraft(dsAmsReference,'<%=DS_AMS_REFERENCE%>')"/>
</div>
```

Abaixo o JS para completar o form.

```
function completaDraft(dsAmsReference) { 

        dataString = "acao=CPD&dsAmsReference="+dsAmsReference;
        dataString = dataString+"&dsAmsReference="+dsAmsReference;
        //alert(dataString); return false;
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: cfgUrl+"draft-acoes.asp",  
            data: dataString,  
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                PaginaAguardeAbre();
            },
            success: function(json) {  
                PaginaAguardeFecha();
                if( json.result.bool() ){
                    ExibeMensagem('Sucesso',"Status da processo alterado com sucesso!","",2500);
                    //$("#formFiltro").submit();
                }else{
                    ExibeMensagem('Aviso',json.erro,"",5000);                       
                }
                return false;
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);         
                enviaLogError(XMLHttpRequest.status, XMLHttpRequest.responseText,this.url,this.data);
                verificaLogado(XMLHttpRequest.status, XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader("URL_REDIRECT"));
                PaginaAguardeFecha();               
                ExibeMensagem('Erro',"Desculpe, mas ocorreu um erro. Por favor, tente novamente.","",4000);
                RequestEnviado = 0;
                return false;   
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Erro pós alteração do Script

Código do ValidarInput e do Select feito por ele.

```
   <% 
Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Expiresabsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" 

dim dsAmsReference

set     objBD   = new ConectaBD 'INSTÂNCIA A CLASSE 
call    objBD.AbrirConexao


dsAmsReference  = codificar(request("dsAmsReference"))

If PAG_TOP = "" Then
    PAG_TOP = 1
End If

SQL = "EXEC PR_DRAFT_DRAF_s                                             "
SQL = SQL & " @funcao               = 'S02'                             "
SQL = SQL & ",@DS_AMS_REFERENCE     = '"&dsAmsReference&"'              "
SQL = SQL & ",@ID_CD_LOGIN  = '"&SESSION("ID_CD_LOGIN")&"' "
'response.write(SQL)
QueryToJSON(objConJson, SQL).Flush
objConJson.close
Set objConJson = Nothing
%>
```

------------ SQL abaixo -----------

```
if @funcao = 'S02'
begin
    SELECT
        DS_AMS_REFERENCE
    FROM TB_BOOKING_BOOK
    WHERE DS_AMS_REFERENCE = @DS_AMS_REFERENCE
    ORDER BY DS_AMS_REFERENCE
end
```

Comment: Não é só fazer um pedido ajax ao servidor com o valor desse input e validar retornando true ou false conforme o resultado? É só copiar esse código de completar o form e só alterar o url.

Comment: Eu faria o mesmo código do completaDraft porém mudando a url para que? Não entendi direito, porque esse completaDraft serve pra chamar os campos do form.

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi corretamente deixava o input só assim:

```
<input type="submit" value="Validar Ref" onclick="mostraCampos();"/>
```

E nesse método faria um pedido ajax parecido com o abaixo, onde o método ValidarInput deverá retornar *true* ou *false* conforme o campo `dsAmsReference` esteja válido ou não, e só assim mostrar e preencher o form. É isso?

```
function mostraCampos() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ValidarInput",
    data: $("#dsAmsReference").val(),
    success: function(result) {
      if (result == true) {
        document.getElementById("dsAmsReference").style.display = "block";
        completaDraft($("#dsAmsReference").val());
      } else {
        document.getElementById("dsAmsReference").style.display = "none";
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: É isso sim cara,mas como eu faço pra validar o dsAmsReference no banco? Crio um novo asp com o nome de ValidarInput onde ele faça um select no banco e valide que o que foi digitado está dentro da table?                                            
                                                                                                                               
E sobre o outro método do input, ele está ali pois quando validado o dsAmsReference e o form aparecendo alguns dados vem direto do banco para que o usuário complete os campos restantes.

Comment: É exatamente isso @PietroRey, experimenta e se tiveres dúvidas coloca aí.

Comment: Então @iamdlm toda vez que clico no botão ele me retorna um erro como se tivesse problema em um script te uma outra página. Não sei se meu select está errado ou se é a página(ValidarInput)que não está feita corretamente, irei postar o código de ambos, se puder me ajudar novamente ficaria grato.